# WxPython - Panel with dynamically added rows does not fit into the frame

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a BoxSizer with 3 panels inside :

1. Title Panel
2. A scrollable panel with a GridBagSizer
3. Back Button Panel

I dynamically add rows in the GridBagSizer, but it does not fit into the available space in the panel.
After I manually resize the frame, it fits!
I tried putting `.Layout` everywhere with no results

My code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled


class Myframe(wx.Frame):                                                    # Create Frame 
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="List")
        self.Center()
        a = self.GetSize()
        MyContainerMenu(self)                               # Main Menu
        self.Layout()


class MyContainerMenu(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(513, 728), style=wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
        e = wx.Button(self, label="Show list")
        panelloc = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        panelloc.AddStretchSpacer()
        panelloc.Add(e, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        panelloc.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.SetSizer(panelloc)
        self.Layout()
        e.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.DeleteChar, e)
        self.Layout()
        panelloc.Layout()

    def DeleteChar(self, event):                  # Destroy Main Menu and creates the list
        c = self.GetParent()
        self.Destroy()
        MyContainerPanel(c, c.GetSize())


class MyContainerPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, size):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=size)
        twopanel = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        a = MyPanelA(self)                                       # Title goes here
        b = MyPanel(self)                                   # List with scroll bar
        bakk = wx.Button(self, label="Back")                   # "Back" button goes here
        twopanel.Add(a, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        twopanel.Add(b, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        twopanel.Add(bakk, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(twopanel)
        self.Layout()
        twopanel.Layout()


class MyPanelA(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(120, 120))
        self.SetBackgroundColour((30, 18, 18))
        title_del = wx.StaticText(self, size=(20, 30), label="TITLE", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL)
        title_del.SetForegroundColour('goldenrod')
        siz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        siz.Add(title_del, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(siz)


class MyPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):                           # PAnel with scroll
    def __init__(self, parent):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour((58, 18, 18))
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        f = wx.GridBagSizer(100, 40)
        self.SetSizer(f)
        ub = 0                                     # Add rows into the sizer dinamically
        names = ["Curly", "Moe", "Larry", "Shemp", "Joe", "Michelangelo", "Raphael", "Donatello", "Leonardo"]
        for x in names:
            a = wx.StaticText(self, label=x, style=wx.EXPAND)
            f.Add(a, pos=(ub, 1))
            ub += 1
        self.Layout()
        f.Layout()


class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = Myframe()
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True


app = App()

app.MainLoop()
```

Edit:

This is what i get:

[image]

This is after i manually resize the frame. Note the scroll bar and the"Back" button

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the data `not fitting` and `fitting`. (You can add images to your question)